# Uvicorn/FastAPI Duplicate Logging

Tags: logging, fastapi, uvicorn

My FastAPI app seems to log many things twice.

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [21360] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [21362]
INFO:uvicorn.error:Started server process [21362]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application startup complete.
^CINFO:     Shutting down
INFO:uvicorn.error:Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [21362]
INFO:uvicorn.error:Finished server process [21362]
INFO:     Stopping reloader process [21360]
```

This includes any exceptions that are raised, you get the entire stack trace twice. I've seen some answers suggest just removing the log handlers for Uvicorn, but this feels wrong. What if there is a logging event that happens at the Uvicorn layer of the stack but not in FastAPI?

Is there a way to get only log output once without just overwriting uvicorn's log handlers?

Comment: See if this helps you: https://pawamoy.github.io/posts/unify-logging-for-a-gunicorn-uvicorn-app/#uvicorn-only-version

Comment: Looks like it might. I guess I'm surprised there is this amount of work to get what I would consider "normal" behavior.

Comment: Yup an unfortunately reality, but hopefully works for you. Been using the gunicorn + uvicorn + fastapi version myself and has been working for last half year or so.

Answer (score 9):

Just remove the `uvicorn` handlers:

```py
logging.getLogger("uvicorn").handlers.clear()
```

Comment: Interesting. I might try that. What are the downsides?

Answer (score 7):

FastAPI doesn't do much logging. How you run `fastapi`, with `gunicorn` or without it? ~~From the info you given, it's not enough to tell where the duplicate comes from.~~ But anyway, we still could get a solution.

`uvicorn.error` is the internal logger used by `uvicorn` for error msg.  `propagate` is the default behavior of this logger. One of the duplicate line must be from handler on `uvicorn.error`, the other is from upper/parent logger.

The solution is to stop msg handled by two logger.

1. Stop setting up handler for parent logger (probably `root` logger)
2. **Or** Disable `uvicorn.error` propagating.

   ```py
   logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error")
   logger.propagate = False
   ```

---

This shouldn't be a problem when running `gunicorn` + `uvicorn` with `UvicornWorker`, when you're using the latest version of uvicorn.

Comment: I was already happy about the first solution proposal, but it did not solve my problem completely because of the uvicorn bootstrap, which emitted the log messages twice.
Fortunately, you mentioned this option with propage, even if I don't understand, how it manages to "propagate" to my custom basic logger... I'm already grateful for your solution, which works, but could you append an explanation for this attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Also in case it helps someone, [this page](https://pawamoy.github.io/posts/unify-logging-for-a-gunicorn-uvicorn-app/) is very helpful. Furthermore, I had an issue where SQLAlchemy was getting initialized *after* setup_logging() from that code was called. Once I changed it to get initialized immediately, my duplicate logs were removed.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but this works for me.

I wanted to remove the default logging done by uvicorn and use my custom logger.

```
logging.getLogger("uvicorn").removeHandler(logging.getLogger("uvicorn").handlers[0])
```

Make sure that you haven't turned off propagation of logs as mentioned in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that `uvicorn` logs were being propagated to the custom logger in the application. I wanted the `uvicorn` logging but not the duplication. setting `propagate=False` from the `uvicorn` logging solves the issue for me.

```
import logging
uvicorn_logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")
uvicorn_logger.propagate = False

app_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```